# Doctrine Relations Menu and Products on Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have two entities, Menu and Products, which are related.
When it comes to displaying the menus, I have an issue where it's not retrieving the related Products that the menu has.

I've been trying a thousand changes for days, but there's no way around it.

What would be the best option?

Menu.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="menu")
 */
class Menu
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nombreMenu;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Domain\Model\Producto")
     */
    private $productos;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->photos = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNombreMenu()
    {
        return $this->nombreMenu;
    }

    public function setNombreMenu($nombreMenu)
    {
        $this->nombreMenu = $nombreMenu;
    }

    public function getProductos()
    {
        return $this->productos;
    }

    public function setProductos($productos)
    {
        $this->productos = $productos;
    }
}
```

product.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="producto")
 */
class Producto
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nombreProducto;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Domain\Model\Menu")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $menus;


    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNombreProducto()
    {
        return $this->nombreProducto;
    }

    public function setNombreProducto($nombreProducto)
    {
        $this->nombreProducto = $nombreProducto;
    }

    public function getMenus()
    {
        return $this->menus;
    }

    public function setMenus($menus)
    {
        $this->menus = $menus;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your relation Menu with Producto is not correct (ManyToMany, with ManyToOne on the other side). It should be One-To-Many, Bidirectional. See the example here: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.16/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional